# How to install Baidu's PaddlePaddle on ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: package, ubuntu-16.04, paddle-paddle

I recently wanted to install PaddlePaddle on ubuntu 16, but there's a missing dependency, the package requires libgflags2, I couldn't find this library on Ubuntu's canonical repos, I found libgflags2v5 instead, so I played a little with the paddle's package dependencies and changed "libgflags2" to "libgflags2v5", and the installation was successful, but the package crashes when I use this command

> paddle train --help

I later on understood that the package works fine on ubuntu 14.04, but unfortunately I can't degrade to that version and I have to use version 16, so how do I deal with this?

EDIT: 
When I run this command

> paddle train --help

I get this error

> I1014 10:38:32.837656  3658 Util.cpp:151] commandline:
>   /usr/bin/../opt/paddle/bin/paddle_trainer --help  
> paddle_trainer:
>   Warning: SetUsageMessage() never called
>  terminate called after
>   throwing an instance of 'std::bad_alloc'
>    what():  std::bad_alloc
>   *** Aborted at 1476434312 (unix time) try "date -d @1476434312" if you are using GNU date**  
> PC: @     0x7f8e7ed14418 gsignal
>    **SIGABRT (@0x3e800000e4a) received by PID 3658 (TID 0x7f8e80e68740) from PID 3658; stack trace: ***
>       @     0x7f8e8075e3d0 (unknown)
>       @     0x7f8e7ed14418 gsignal
>       @     0x7f8e7ed1601a abort
>       @     0x7f8e7f65684d __gnu_cxx::__verbose_terminate_handler()
>       @     0x7f8e7f6546b6 (unknown)
>       @     0x7f8e7f654701 std::terminate()
>       @     0x7f8e7f654919 __cxa_throw
>       @     0x7f8e7f654ebc operator new()
>       @     0x7f8e7f94ee6d (unknown)
>       @     0x7f8e7f94f619 (unknown)
>       @     0x7f8e7f94f830 (unknown)
>       @     0x7f8e7f95629a google::GetAllFlags()
>       @     0x7f8e7f95d707 (unknown)
>       @     0x7f8e7f95dda2 google::ShowUsageWithFlagsRestrict()
>       @     0x7f8e7f95e56f google::HandleCommandLineHelpFlags()
>       @     0x7f8e7f9554db (unknown)
>       @           0x74a8f5 paddle::ParseCommandLineFlags()
>       @           0x748341 paddle::initMain()
>       @           0x509a3b main
>       @     0x7f8e7ecff830 __libc_start_main
>       @           0x515455 (unknown)
>       @                0x0 (unknown) /usr/bin/paddle: line 81:  3658 
> Aborted                 (core dumped) ${DEBUGGER}
>   $MYDIR/../opt/paddle/bin/paddle_trainer ${@:2}

Comment: Just a quick note: you should explicitly say the full version of Ubuntu (e.g. 14.04 and 16.04); Ubuntu 14.04 and 14.10 (and so on) are **entirely different releases**, not patches of version 14.

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: @alvas updated question with error logs

Answer (score 0):

Out of the box installation, see http://www.paddlepaddle.org/doc/build/

For Ubuntu without GPU:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
wget https://github.com/baidu/Paddle/releases/download/V0.8.0b1/paddle-cpu-0.8.0b1-Linux.deb
gdebi paddle-*.deb
sudo paddle version
```

Building from source, see http://www.paddlepaddle.org/doc/build/build_from_source.html

Comment: Still the same problem.

Comment: did you try building from source?

Comment: Nope I didn't, I just rolled back to 14.04 :/

Comment: Compile from source. It should work when you compile from source. There's more steps but it's worth the effort.

Comment: Well, I'll give it a try, since I've had a look into the sources.